# Add model into an existing model RDF

Tags: merge, rdf, jena

I tried to merge 2 existing RDF/XML models. I tried different solutions:

- `model1.union(model2)`
- `model1.add(model2) //adding a complete model`
- `model1.add(model2.listStatements())`

I'm using Jena in Java.

I removed enveloping tags (like `Equipment`) from the second model, but I always have the same problem: the resulting model is not really merged: it contains an envelopment for each added model. E.g., I have 2 documents, but different endpoints. They should be merged to have one document which contains all data:

bookid123 in endpointA

```xml
<rdf:RDF
xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
xmlns:si="http://www.w3schools.com/rdf/">
<rdf:Description rdf:about="http://endpointA/bookid123">
  <si:title>W3Schools.com</si:title>
</rdf:Description>
</rdf:RDF>
```

bookid123 in endpointB

```xml
<rdf:RDF
xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
xmlns:si="http://www.w3schools.com/rdf/">
<rdf:Description rdf:about="http://endpointB/bookid123">
  <si:author>Jan Egil Refsnes</si:author>
</rdf:Description>
</rdf:RDF>
```

As result, I something like this:

```xml
<rdf:RDF
xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
xmlns:si="http://www.w3schools.com/rdf/">
<rdf:Description rdf:about="http://endpointA/bookid123">
  <si:title>W3Schools.com</si:title>
</rdf:Description>
<rdf:Description rdf:about="http://endpointB/bookid123">
  <si:author>Jan Egil Refsnes</si:author>
</rdf:Description>
</rdf:RDF>
```

but I need something like this:

```xml
<rdf:RDF
xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
xmlns:si="http://www.w3schools.com/rdf/">
<rdf:Description rdf:about="http://couldbeanything/bookid123">
  <si:title>W3Schools.com</si:title>
  <si:author>Jan Egil Refsnes</si:author>
</rdf:Description>
</rdf:RDF>
```

Is there a smarter way than getting every statement of `model1`, adding them to `model2`, except statements which are different because of the source-uri?

Comment: Neither of those snippets are valid RDF/XML, so I doubt that the first one is what you get, and I doubt that the second one is what you want! You probably already know that RDF is defined in terms of subject-predicate-object triples, so it would help if you said what triples you have in each model, and what triples you want in the final model. Talking about XML tags just confuses things. Also, what library are you using? I guess it's Apache Jena, but there are many RDF libraries out there.

Comment: I edited my examples and added more information. You're right, I'm using the jena libary in a java project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In RDF, the identifiers are complete URI's and they are not considered part of any document you happen to find them in. So in your example,

```
http://endpointA/bookid123
http://endpointB/bookid123
```

are unique and independent names for things. So it is quite correct from an RDF perspective that merge will not combine triples with those subjects together.

In your case, you are wanting to assert that, by some means outside of the RDF model, you *know* that `http://endpointA/bookid123` and `http://endpointB/bookid123` are actually the same resource and that therefore statements about one can be considered to be also statements about the other.

There are two ways to handle this. Firstly, you could use OWL to express that the two resources denote the same individual (I'll use Turtle syntax for brevity, it doesn't change the meaning):

```
<http://endpointA/bookid123> owl:sameAs <http://endpointB/bookid123> .
```

In order for this to work, you'll need to use a model with an OWL reasoner (such as `OWL_MEM_MICRO_RULE_INF`) attached.

The second way is more brute force: for each two resources `resource1` and `resource2` that you want to merge, run a loop to copy the statements of one to also be statement of the other:

```
for (StmtIterator i = resource1.listStatements(); i.hasNext(); ) {
    Statement s = i.next();
    resource2.addProperty( s.getPredicate(), s.getObject() );
}
```

Comment: thanks, I tested the second one and it worked. But this seems to be limited. I will have a look at owl:sameAs. It seems to be the same in rdfs --> rdfs:seeAlso. Your example above is a sparql query? Because I have to add a sameAs-Resource to my RDF/XML-Document like this: <rdfs:sameAs rdf:resource="http://endpointB/bookid123"/> ?

Comment: No, `owl:sameAs` and `rdfs:seeAlso` are not the same concepts at all. `sameAs` has the interpretation, in OWL, that two resources *literally* denote the same individual. The meaning is quite precise. `seeAlso` *informally* means that the object URI is a document that *might* add more information about the subject resource. As I wrote in the answer, the fragment of RDF is encoded in Turtle. If you want to work with RDF, don't think about the syntax (RDF/XML, Turtle, whatever) but think about the triples in the graph. Trying to write Jena code in terms of RDF/XML will just confuse you.

Comment: Incidentally, to learn about Turtle see the Jena documentation or this page: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turtle_%28syntax%29

Comment: thanks, but I still have no idea how to get the merged content. The content provided by endpointA has following structure: '<rdf:RDF
xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
xmlns:si="http://www.w3schools.com/rdf/"
xmlns:owl="http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#">
<rdf:Description rdf:about="http://endpointA/bookid123">
  <owl:sameAs rdf:resource="http://endpointB/bookid123"/>
  <si:title>W3Schools.com</si:title>
</rdf:Description>
</rdf:RDF>' Where do I merge? In the program code (e.g. java) or at the frontend(eg. sparql query)?

Comment: If you use a Jena `OntModel` with OWL inference enabled, the two resources will have the same properties in the merged model.